# Multilingual lucene search returns one result only

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, cjk

I am developing lucene search in Japanese language. I am using org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.JapaneseAnalyzer during indexing and searching. The indexing is happening successfully.

For searching following is the code:

`JapaneseAnalyzer japaneseAnalyzer = new JapaneseAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT);
                qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "keywords", japaneseAnalyzer);
qp.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
keywords = "/*whatever the search query is*/";`

'keywords' is being processed using multiple filters.

`Query query = qp.parse(keywords.toString());
TopFieldDocs docs = searcher.search(query, 5000000);`

The docs is returning one result only, whereas it should be returning 4.

Is there anything that is missing from my side? Or can I add anything to improve the accuracy?
I have already set the boost on the field level to 9.0f.

Comment: have you tried analyzing your index with Luke?

Comment: source here: https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke

Comment: hmm, can I ask what exactly are you passing in this variable? `keywords = "/*whatever the search query is*/"`